# Explanation for CPU minutes/ day azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Will I be charged if I host my application on Azure App Service more than 60 min even if my app does not do any processing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answer is **NO**.

Under App Service -> App Service Plan -> Quotas you can see a detailed breakdown of usage such as an example below for a website I created hours ago but showing only 1.11 minutes of usage:

[image: Quota for a free App Service Plan]

I got the answer from AjayKumar-MSFT's answer from [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/aa45c5f4-9395-482f-9f33-3b6656bd181e/cpu-capacity-per-day-regarding-shared-tier-of-azure-website?forum=windowsazurepurchasing) at a Microsoft forum, then proceeded to test it myself.

Answer (score 6):

You could go serverless with Azure Functions, host in a Consumption plan and only pay for execution time. It's a bit more complicated than that but in essence you don't pay for idle code, which i believe is what you're after.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/

> Functions are billed based on observed resource consumption measured in gigabyte seconds (GB-s). **Observed resource consumption is calculated by multiplying average memory size in gigabytes by the time in milliseconds it takes to execute the function**. Memory used by a function is measured by rounding up to the nearest 128 MB, up to the maximum memory size of 1,536 MB, with execution time calculated by rounding up to the nearest 1 ms. The minimum execution time and memory for a single function execution is 100 ms and 128 mb respectively. **Functions pricing includes a monthly free grant of 400,000 GB-s**.

A very detailed example is found under that URL.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is NO. if CPU time exceeds no charge will cost rather site will be stopped and it will be working after a certain time next day. Under App Service -> App Service Plan -> Quotas you can get details of CPU time and memory. It is clearly mentioned in Quotas that Applications hosted in a free or shared App Service plan are subject to usage quotas. If any quota is exceeded the site will be stopped until that quota resets. You can remove quotas on your app by scaling up your App Service Plan.

Answer (score -1):

The costs depend on the pricing plan you choose for your app. There are several plans available to choose from. You could choose the Free plan and you won't incur costs but this plan is mostly meant for experimenting with the platform. It doesn't provide any SLA.
You can find more details about the pricing at the following links

- [App Service pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/)
- [App Service Plans](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/)

And yes, your app will incur costs even if it is not consuming any CPU since it is allocated resource (a VM) and is running.

Comment: This answer is wrong, when the website is inactive, it doesn't count as consuming CPU, so you can run the website under a free plan for 24 hours as long as the cumulative CPU doesn't exceed 60 minutes per day.  See my forthcoming answer.